# Failed to find Build Tools revision

Tags: android, gradle, build

gradle не может найти build tools хотя необходимая версия установлена. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в файле local.properties (должен находится в папке AgeOfWar), что написано?

Comment: путь к сдк: sdk.dir=/home/denis/Android/Sdk больше ничего нет

Comment: Попробуй через менеджер пакета поставить build tool 24.0.0 и поменять свойство в gradle файле.

Comment: после перезапуска все излечилось само сабой

Comment: Начиная с версии 3.0 Android плагина, нет необходимости указывать версию build tools. Плагин будет использовать нужную версию автоматически. [Пруф](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#behavior_changes)